# Убираем тэги HTML

Tags: html, php

Столкнулся с проблемой, не знаю, как убирать тэги html... Суть в том, что на моём сайте можно отправлять сообщения и текст сообщения записывается в базу данных, а потом достаётся. И если использовать в сообщении теги типа: `<div> </div>`, то они воспринимаются как html тэги, а не текст. Вроде их можно заменять на `&lt;` и `&gt;`

Сайт пишу на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php)

```
$html = '<div> =) </div>';
$html = htmlentities( $html );
echo $html; // -> &lt;div&gt; =) &lt;/div&gt;
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но что-то не очень... я помещаю в эту функцию всё сообщение, и вот что с ним происходит:

>`&acirc;&icirc;&ograve; &egrave;&ntilde;&iuml;&icirc;&euml;&uuml;&ccedil;&oacute;&eacute; &yacute;&ograve;&icirc;&ograve; &ecirc;&icirc;&auml;))`

>`&lt;div id=&quot;new_mail&quot;&gt; &acirc;&eth;&icirc;&auml;&aring; &aacute;&ucirc; &eth;&icirc;&aacute;&egrave;&ograve;)) &lt;/div&gt;`

Comment: Всё, я нашёл ответ.

Нужно просто использовать не `htmlentities()`, а `htmlspecialchars()`, тогда всё нормально.